# Java Pattern regex subtraction with greedy quantifiers

Tags: java, regex, string, subtraction

I am currently trying to use a regex to validate that my input has a certain format.
In the possible input there is only one combination of characters that I don't wan't to match.
Therefore I would like to use the subtraction as described in the [JavaDoc for the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

[a-z&&[^bc]]    a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)

So it is possible to exclude a certain pattern of characters from my expression.
Unfortunetly I was not able to get the regex right.

The pattern should match a String of exactly 8 digits ([0-9]{8}). Furthermore it should not match for the String of exactly 8 zero characters.

- 12345678 -> match yes
- 00000001 -> match yes
- 00000000 -> macth no

So this is how I tried it: regex = "[[0-9]{8}]&&[^[0{8}]]"

My Question now is, how can I group multiple characters together for a match.

Or how would the regex have to look like to meet my requirements.

Would be nice if somebody could help me with that.

Comment: If memory serves, you can use a pair of parentheses to define a *group* of characters to match. Add in `?:` at the beginning (I think) if saving the value of the group for later isn't important.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it isn't working if try: regex = "?:[[0-9]{8}]&&[^[0{8}]]". But maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't what I meant. You're better off with Tim's answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you're better off with a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regex = "^(?!0{8})[0-9]{8}$"
```

A character class always matches a single character from a certain set, and that set is defined in the expression between square brackets, which is why your approach doesn't work.

`[[0-9]{8}]&&[^[0{8}]]` actually means

```
[[0-9]{8} # Match 8 characters between 0 and 9 or a "["
]&&       # Match literal "]&&"
[^[0{8}]  # Match a character except "[", "0", "{", "8", or "}"
]         # Match a literal "]"
```

A solution without lookaround would have to make sure that at least one nonzero digit is present, while still making sure that the overall number of digits is exactly 8. That makes it complicated:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{7}|[0-9][1-9][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]{5}|[0-9]{3}[1-9][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}[1-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[1-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{6}[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{7}[1-9])$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                     # Start of string
(?:                   # Start of group
[1-9][0-9]{7}         # Match digit > 0, followed by 7 digits
|                     # or
[0-9][1-9][0-9]{6}    # Match any digit, a digit 1-9, 6 other digits
|                     # or
[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]{5} # Match 2 digits, a digit 1-9, 5 other digits
|                     # or
...                   # etc. etc. etc.
)                     # End of group
$                     # End of string
```

Comment: Nice! thanks for your help it works. Isn't there any other solution. Or can you tell me why my approach is wrong?

Comment: @milius: Of course there are other solutions, but they will be more complicated. Your approach doesn't work because character class subtraction is used to shorten the list of valid *characters* which a class can match, not the list of valid *matches* a regex can have - that's what lookaround assertions are there for. See also my explanation of your regex above. I will add an alternative solution shortly that will show you why this approach is the best one.